# How to allow user to search without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have the following three dropdownlist and a button which gives a result based on the selected criterias:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="slcLocation" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="slcSpecialty" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="slcGender" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Any Gender" Value="" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnGoAll" Text="Search All" OnClick="btnGoAll_Click" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

The first two dropdownlist populates using code-behind function.

How can I allow the user to select all three options and hit the search button to display the result without refreshing the page?

I tried something like this:

```
<div style="width: 390px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="slcLocation" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="width: 365px;" class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="slcSpecialty" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="width: 365px;" class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="slcGender" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="width: 365px;" class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Any Gender" Value="" Selected="True" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="slcLocation" />
        </Triggers>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="slcSpecialty" />
        </Triggers>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="slcGender" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div style="width: 390px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <asp:HyperLink class="loginButton" style="padding: 10px; float: right;" runat="server" ID="aSearchSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnGoAll_Click" Text="Search" />
</div>
```

I update my Repeater with the data retrieved from the search:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="0" ID="tblInfo" style="background: #43A79A; width: 100%;" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <tr>
                    <td>Physician Name</td>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Office1</td>
                    <td>Office2</td>
                    <td>Office3</td>
                    <td>Office4</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Physician Name").ToString() %></td>
                <td><img src="www.site.com/<%# Eval("Image").ToString() %>" /></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Gender").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office1").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office2").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office3").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office4").ToString() %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: try putting the button within the content template and add a async postback trigger to it

Comment: just to add as far as i know Hyperlink doesnt have a OnClick event

Comment: Yes you are right, I have to fix that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what do you want is this.

You need set how updatePanel´s trigger the button.

The part of page what do you want update need to be inside the updatepanel.

The javascript will catch DropDownList changes, and after all three DropDownList were changed the postback will be raised like if you was clicked in button

aspx

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var slcLocationSelect = false;
    var slcSpecialtySelect = false;
    var slcGenderSelect = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=slcLocation.ClientID %>").change(function () { changeDropDown(this) });
        $("#<%=slcSpecialty.ClientID %>").change(function () { changeDropDown(this) });
        $("#<%=slcGender.ClientID %>").change(function () { changeDropDown(this) });
    });
    function changeDropDown(sender) {
        if ($(event.target).attr('id') == $("#<%=slcLocation.ClientID %>").attr('id')) {
            slcLocationSelect = true;
        }
        if ($(event.target).attr('id') == $("#<%=slcSpecialty.ClientID %>").attr('id')) {
            slcSpecialtySelect = true;
        }
        if ($(event.target).attr('id') == $("#<%=slcGender.ClientID %>").attr('id')) {
            slcGenderSelect = true;
        }
        if (slcLocationSelect && slcSpecialtySelect && slcGenderSelect) {
            slcLocationSelect = false;
            slcSpecialtySelect = false;
            slcGenderSelect = false;
            __doPostBack("<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>", "");
        }
    }
</script>
<div style="width: 390px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="slcLocation" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="width: 365px;"
        class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="slcSpecialty" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="width: 365px;"
        class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="slcGender" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="width: 365px;"
        class="default" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Any Gender" Value="" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="width: 390px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Find</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <div style="width: 100%;">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table border="0" id="tblInfo" style="background: #43A79A; width: 100%;" clientidmode="Static">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Physician Name
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Image
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Gender
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Office1
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Office2
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Office3
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Office4
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Physician Name").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="www.site.com/<%# Eval("Image").ToString() %>" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Gender").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Office1").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Office2").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Office3").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Office4").ToString() %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

cs

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = slcGender.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When I add the AutoPostBack="True" for the dropdownlist, everytime I select a choice the page refreshes.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Yes, that's by design. If you don't want the entire page to refresh, then add them as asynchronous triggers on the UpdatePanel.

Comment: So add another UpdatePanel and put all three inside that panel and have a trigger for each?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to remove AutoPostBack="True.

Comment: I will go ahead and update my code and see if it works. Thanks. I am using a Repeater to display the data, do I have to put that inside UpdatePanel?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Do  you want select all three dropDown and aft click in the button update the page?. This is correct?

Comment: Yes. You put all elements that will update inside the updatepanel

Comment: I updated my question. I am not sure if it's possible but when the user selects all/no option and clicks search the search is displayed without page refresh... Or is it not recommended?

Comment: This is possible, I'm going home. When I arrive there, I will help you

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I update the aspx code, I include some JavaScript that does what do you asked.

Comment: I can just use the DIV because I have clientIDmode="static"

Comment: The Repeater which is displaying the data doesn't need an UpdatePanel right?

Comment: I think your Repeater need to be inside the UpdatePanel like new code´s update that I did

Comment: WOW... didn't even see the update :)! Thanks. I will check it out... and let you know if it work :)

Comment: Don't need the Javascript as I don't want to perform any search without using clicking the SEARCH button. Thanks. I will update you once I have tested everything.